# get listview row onContextItemSelected

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I'm doing a proyect where i have a view with multiple listview created at runtime, every listview load specifics rows of a database. and i want to implement a contextmenu. The problem is how can i get the row of the listview to retieve the id of the database? How can i get my list adapter inside the contextmenu ? or some other solution. Thanks!
here is a part of the code...

```
private void makeView(){

   yearsArray = db.getUniqueYears(TABLE_NAME);

   for (int i = 0; i <  yearsArray.size()  ; i++){

        list = db.getDocByYear(TABLE_NAME,  yearsArray.get(i));
        custom_adapter = new Document_adapter(this, list);
        ListView lv = new ListView(this);
        lv.setAdapter(custom_adapter);
        lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.title_container_bg);
        registerForContextMenu(lv);

        }
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.doc_options, menu);


}

  @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    /* 

            */


    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you set your database up properly you can just do this `info.id;` in your `onContextItemSelected` and that gives the database id

Comment: Actually that works perfectly, thanks! Total newbie of my part.